# why can not i use the transpose function without :?

Tags: torch

i want to transpose a tensor in torch/lua.
actually i didn't fully get the idea of ":" but it really frustrates me
i am a beginner to lua and torch.
only this works :

> x:t()

i want to do this

> x = torch.t(x)

and when i do it i see error

> attempt to call field 't' (a nil value)

i tried to search for a solution on the internet but i didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lua, `x:method(args)` is syntactic sugar for `x.method(x, args)`. It is a way to omit the `self` parameter.

This being said, the easiest way to transpose a 2D tensor `x` is indeed `x:t()`. You can also write `x.t(x)` but it is more complicated.

Finally `torch` does not have a method `transpose` or `t` as a field (unlike `squeeze` for example for which you can do both `torch.squeeze(x)` and `x:squeeze()`), I don't know the reason for this choice but it does not seem too painful to write `x:t()` and it is also the notation that is the closest to the mathematical notation, which I find convenient.